# Pandas give me AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean' when I try to create categories based on the standard deviations the value lies

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

Hi I am trying to create a new data frame by categorizing the values for the different columns in the original data frame. The code is shown below.

```
def get_sections(column):
column_mean = column.mean()
column_std = column.std()
column_2std = 2* column_std
column_3std = 3* column_std
return column_mean, column_std, column_2std, column_3std

def get_category(column):
get_sections(column)
if (column_mean + column_3std) < column:
    return 'A'
elif (column_mean + column_2std) < column <= (column_mean + column_3std):
    return 'B'
elif (column_mean + column_std) < column <= (column_mean + column_2std):
    return 'C'
elif (column_mean - column_std) < column <= (column_mean + column_std):
    return 'D'
elif (column_mean - column_2std) < column <= (column_mean - column_std):
    return 'E'
elif (column_mean - column_3std) < column <= (column_mean - column_2std):
    return 'F'
else:
    return 'G'

for col in df_original.columns:
df_category[col + "_Category"] = df_original[col].map(get_category)
```

However when I run my script I got this error

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean'

Am just curious where did I go wrong since I can get the results if I do it manually on individual columns. How should I solve this?

Comment: post your dataframe

Comment: you are using map which is mapping elementwise. instead of passing series you are passing a float value that's why. Your logic is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

Correction:

Your logic for comparing is completely wrong. You were comparing series with a value. So you should use `gt, le etc` along with that use `np.select` if value comes under the range then assign them values.

---

```
def get_sections(column):
    column_mean = column.mean()
    column_std = column.std()
    column_2std = 2* column_std
    column_3std = 3* column_std
    return column_mean, column_std, column_2std, column_3std

def get_category(column):
    column_mean, column_std, column_2std, column_3std = get_sections(df_original[column.name])

    conditions  = [ (column).gt(column_mean + column_3std), (column).gt(column_mean + column_2std) & column.le(column_mean + column_3std),
                  (column).gt(column_mean + column_std) & column.le(column_mean + column_2std),
                  (column).gt(column_mean + column_std) & column.le(column_mean + column_std),
                  (column).gt(column_mean - column_2std) & column.le(column_mean - column_std),
                  (column).gt(column_mean - column_3std) & column.le(column_mean - column_2std),
                   
                  ]
    choices     = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' ]

    return (np.select(conditions, choices, default='G'))

# for col in df_original.columns:
df_original.apply(lambda x: get_category(x),axis=0)
```

---

**sample_dataframe:**

```
df_original = pd.DataFrame({'vote_average': [7.2, 6.9, 6.3, 7.6, 6.1, 5.9, 7.4, 7.3, 7.4, 5.7, 5.4],
                   'vote_count': [11800, 4500, 4466, 9106, 2124, 3576, 3330, 6767, 5293, 7004, 1400]})
```

---

**Output I got:**

|  | vote_average | vote_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | G | B |
| 1 | G | G |
| 2 | G | G |
| 3 | C | C |
| 4 | G | E |
| 5 | G | G |
| 6 | G | G |
| 7 | G | G |
| 8 | G | G |
| 9 | E | G |
| 10 | E | E |

**Edit:**

```
res = pd.concat([df_original, df_original.apply(lambda x: get_category(x),axis=0).add_suffix('_changed')],axis=1)
```

**res:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pygirl. df_original.apply(lambda x: get_category(x),axis=0) basically replaces the values with the category. But what if the intention is to create new columns such as vote_average_category and vote_count_category. How should we change the syntax?

Comment: @DanielChang: I have updated the answer check now. I hope this helps. If it helps then close the question by accepting it as an answer :)